# Very simple index notation question

Tags: notation, differentiation

Trying to understand index notation in the context of spacetime. If I have $x^{\mu}$
  and then set $\mu=\phi$
  (for example), is it acceptable to then write $x^{\phi}$
  or should I just write $\phi$? For example, can I write $$\frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial x^{\mu}}$$
 as $$\frac{\partial g_{\phi\nu}}{\partial x^{\phi}},$$
 or should I stick with$$\frac{\partial g_{\phi\nu}}{\partial\phi}?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there is some problem with your notation.

Disclaimer: what follows are conventions, so they could be not universally respected, although I think this is what is mostly followed.

Reading
$$ \frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial x^\mu} = \partial_\mu g_{\mu \nu} $$
in its  *literal* sense, it is not a relativistic expression, since you are contracting two lower indices. So in this case *no sum is implied*: $\mu$ is fixed. Now you can do two *different* things.

1. If you set $\mu =\phi$ you are just relabelling the index and so you can write
   $$ \frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial x^\mu} = \frac{\partial g_{\phi\nu}}{\partial x^\phi} = \partial_\phi g_{\phi \nu}  .$$
2. Not being a relativistic expression you can specialise in some frame of reference where you can choose particular coordinates, like spherical coordinates, in which you call $x^\mu = \phi$ for *some fixed* index $\mu$, for instance $\mu =2$. In this case $\phi$ is not an index but is is a coordinate. Then you'd have
   $$ \frac{\partial g_{\phi\nu}}{\partial \phi} = \partial_\phi g_{\phi \nu} = \frac{\partial g_{2\nu}}{\partial x^2} = \partial_2 g_{2 \nu} .$$

On the other hand, if by your writing you mean
$$ \frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial x_\mu} = \partial^\mu g_{\mu\nu}=\sum_{\mu=0}^3  \frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial x_\mu}= \sum_\mu \partial^\mu g_{\mu\nu} 
  $$
(note that the position of indices, different from yours!)
this is a relativistic expression and there is a sum implied unless differently stated. Then you can rename the index $\mu$ calling it $\phi$ because it is a dummy index, and you get
$$ \frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial x_\mu} =  \frac{\partial g_{\phi\nu}}{\partial x_\phi} =\sum_{\phi=0}^3 
 \frac{\partial g_{\phi\nu}}{\partial x_\phi}  $$
In this context an expression like $$ \frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial \mu} =  \frac{\partial g_{\phi\nu}}{\partial \phi} =\sum_{\phi=0}^3 
 \frac{\partial g_{\phi\nu}}{\partial \phi}  $$
is not conventionally defined.

---

**Other clarifications:**

In using spherical coordinates $x^\mu = (x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)=(t,r,\theta,\phi)$, $\phi$ and $\theta$ are *coordinates*, not *indices*. In (consistent) index notation, where $x^3=\phi$ and $x^2=\theta$, you want to compute 
$$\Gamma_{33}^2 = 1/2 g^{2\mu}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^3} g_{\mu 3}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x^3} g_{3 \mu} - \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} g_{33}\right);$$
here $3$ and $\mu$ are *indices*; moreover on the previous expression there is a sum over $\mu$ implied.

Since $x^3 = \phi$, then $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^3}=\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}$$ and so on. *They are just different names*. So:
$$\Gamma_{33}^2 = 1/2 g^{2\mu}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} g_{\mu 3}+\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} g_{3 \mu} - \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} g_{33}\right).$$

Now  it comes the slight abuse of notation. Since it is easier to think and remember the 'real' coordinates rather than confusing indices, we write $\Gamma_{\phi\phi}^\theta$ rather than $\Gamma_{33}^2$, $g_{\mu \theta}$ rather than $g_{\mu 2}$ and so on; I would then write $$\Gamma_{\phi\phi}^\theta= \Gamma_{33}^2 = 1/2 g^{\theta\mu}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} g_{\mu \phi}+\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} g_{\phi \mu} - \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} g_{\phi\phi}\right).$$ Remember that you have still an implied sum over $\mu$. Probably in the particular metric you are studying there are some symmetries that allow you to restrict to just one term, the one with $\mu = 2$ (but this could also not happen in other cases), then 
$$\Gamma_{\phi\phi}^\theta=1/2 g^{\theta\theta}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} g_{\theta \phi}+\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} g_{\phi \theta} - \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} g_{\phi\phi}\right),$$
with no sum implied anymore.

---

So now that you have clarified the context I can complete the answer by saying that in your question there is a mistake:

You did *not* put $\mu = \phi$ for $\mu=3$, but rather $x^\mu = \phi$ for $\mu =3$, or $x^3=\phi$.

Comment: So, for example, $\Gamma_{\phi\phi}^{\theta}=\frac{1}{2}g^{\theta\theta}\left(\frac{\partial g_{\theta\phi}}{\partial x^{\phi}}+\frac{\partial g_{\phi\theta}}{\partial x^{\phi}}-\frac{\partial g_{\phi\phi}}{\partial x^{\theta}}\right)$
  is correct, as it's a balanced equation. But $\Gamma_{\phi\phi}^{\theta}=\frac{1}{2}g^{\theta\theta}\left(\frac{\partial g_{\theta\phi}}{\partial\phi}+\frac{\partial g_{\phi\theta}}{\partial\phi}-\frac{\partial g_{\phi\phi}}{\partial x^{\theta}}\right)$
  is wrong, as the indices now don't balance? Is that right?

Comment: @Peter4075 I do not exactly know the meaning of your formulae because it depends on the context. If I guess correctly, $\theta$ and $\phi$ are (angular) coordinates, right? in this case you are working in a particular coordinate system where $x^\mu = (t,r,\theta,\phi)$. Then, provided you write $\theta$ for $x^\theta$, the second one is fine as long as you are discarding other terms that (I think by guessing the context) are zero and there is no sum implied,whereas the first is meaningless because $x^\theta$  and $x^\phi$ are undefined ($x^2= \theta$ etc)

Comment: Ok, another point. $x^mu = (t,r,\theta,\phi)$. If you want the Christoffel symbol relative to the coordinates $\theta$ and $\phi\phi$ what you need is to compute $\Gamma_{33}^2$. Since $x^2=\theta$ and $x^3=\phi$, it is conventional but slightly an abuse, to write it as $\Gamma_{\phi\phi}^\theta$. The same holds for $g_{\mu \nu}$, where, for instance, it is often written $g_{rr}$ for $g_{11}$ as well

Comment: Yes, I was trying to calculate the connection coefficients for the surface of a unit sphere in polar coordinates. Sorry to labour the point, but are you saying that it's acceptable to use notation such as $\Gamma_{\phi\phi}^{\theta}=\frac{1}{2}g^{\theta\theta}\left(\frac{\partial g_{\theta\phi}}{\partial x^{\phi}}+\frac{\partial g_{\phi\theta}}{\partial x^{\phi}}-\frac{\partial g_{\phi\phi}}{\partial x^{\theta}}\right)$
  as long as it's in the context of a specific calculation where I've defined $x^{\mu}=\left(t,r,\theta,\phi\right)$ ?

Comment: No, what you write is wrong: $\phi$ and $\theta$ are *coordinates*, not *indices*. In index notation, where $x^3=\phi$ and $x^2=\theta$, you want to compute

Comment: Whoops, I think I've asked a confused question. I realise $x^{\phi}$
  and $x^{\theta}$
  are coordinates and not indices. What I wanted to know is is it acceptable to write $x^{\phi}$
  for the coordinate $\phi$,
  as in the equation in my previous comment. Another example might be $\frac{\partial g_{\phi\phi}}{\partial x^{\theta}}=\frac{\partial\left(\sin^{2}\theta\right)}{\partial\theta}=2\sin\theta\cos\theta$.
  Is $x^{\theta}$ OK to represent $\theta$?

Comment: Sorry the comment was to long and I edited the answer, maybe now it's clearer. (actually I thought I had deleted that comment... sorry for that)

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course that is completely acceptable. You can say $x^\mu=x^\nu=(ct,r,\theta,\phi)$ The $\mu, \nu$ or whatever else are at your discretion as long as you are consistent. With respect to your derivative the first two make sense. The third derivative is a legitimate expression but it means that you are taking the derivative of $g_{\phi \nu}$ with respect to the coordinate $\phi$.
Normally you would write $x^\mu$ where $mu=(0,1,...)$. So with what I've written above  $x^\mu=x^\nu=(ct,r,\theta,\phi)$ where $\mu,\nu=(0,1,2,3)$ and then $\frac{\partial g_{\sigma\nu}}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial g_{\sigma \nu}}{\partial \theta}$.
Note: that is not an $x^2$ like x-squared.
I should also say that if you meant that $x^\phi=\phi$ then all three derivatives in your question are good to go.